# Tailor made for?

Tags: meaning

It is very common in sports commentary, commentator saying it a tailor made situation for a team. What does that mean ? and what is the origin of it?

Comment: *Tailor made* is the opposing idiom to *off the shelf*. Does that help?

Comment: It means the same as "bespoke".  Look up "tailor" and figure it out.

Comment: (Or simply Google "tailor made".)  (You should do some research before you post questions here.)

Comment: Often hyphenated _tailor-made_, or joined without space _tailormade_. A brand name for early cigarettes (cf "Trouble" from _The Music Man_), and an old phrase referring to clothing especially made for one person by a tailor instead of being bought _ready-to-wear_ from a rack in a store. By metaphoric extension, it's applied to anything that fits its purpose perfectly, especially if it's very expensive and complicated.

Answer (score 1):

A tailor is a maker of clothes. If something is tailor made, it has been cut specifically for a client to fit them perfectly.

Saying that something is tailor made means that it fits a situation or circumstance so well that it appears it could have been made for it.

Comment: Isn't this general reference?

Comment: Possibly. Should I delete?

Comment: It's best not to give answers to basic / easily researched questions, but this one will probably be closed quite soon. You get a feel for how to deal with this sort of question after a while. ELL is for more basic enquiries (though some sign of  research by the questioner is expected there too).

Comment: The compound expression is mostly spelt with a hyphen: a tailor-made suit meaning made by a tailor.